# Отправить токен на сервер

Tags: android

```
package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

Что необходимо указать в sendRegistrationToServer, чтобы передать токен на сервер?

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
}
```

Comment: Очень сложно ответить вам на вопрос, т.к. не ясно какого рода информацию вам надо получить. Судя по коду вы взяли пример из документации, а судя по вопросу имеете очень мало опыта. Коли так, предполагаю, что вам можно ответить так: вам нужен сервер (программа работающая на компе, доступ к коему есть через интернет и принимающая запросы из него), на него надо послать собственно токен. Вот этот код и надо написать. Если сервер есть - то берите либу `Retrofit` и шлите запрос на сервер. Если сервера нет, то у меня для вас плохие новости - придётся его написать, что долго и сложно

Comment: Да, у меня мало опыта разработке на Android. Мне необходимо передать токен FCM на сервер для сохранения в базу данных

Comment: Вы всё ещё не раскрываете деталей того что у вас есть, что вы умеете и в чём вопрос) Если у вас есть сервер, то на нём, видимо, есть метод, принимающий токен и пишущий его в БД. В этом случае берите либу `retrofit`, описывайте там запрос (адрес, параметры) и вызывайте этот метод. Без информации о том что на сервере - что-то ещё сказать сложно. Если же вы её дадите - то вопрос будет не про пуши, а про сетевые запросы в андроид.